# Stop the button from changing its relief when I press it. (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

Greatings! I'm trying to do a simple calculator with Tkinter, what I want is that when I press a button it does not change relief and keeps being `FLAT`. The problem is that it keeps changing to `GROOVE`.

Here is the code line:

```
button1 = tk.Button(self, text="1", command=lambda: self.config(relief=FLAT), relief=FLAT,
                            font=myfont, bg="ghost white", activebackground="LightSteelBlue2")
```

I would appreciate the help.

EDIT

What I want the button to do is something like this, like the buttons of the Windows Calculator[image]

Comment: So instead make it a label and bind Button-1 to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a label if you want it to stay flat even when being pressed. Thought I am not sure why you do not want some visual q to show it has been clicked.

Here is an example using A button and a Label. Notice the label works like a button when we use `bind()` but without visually changing.

```
import tkinter as tk


def do_something(value):
    print(value)


root = tk.Tk()
# Normal button behavior.
tk.Button(root, text="Button 1", relief='flat', bg="ghost white",
          activebackground="LightSteelBlue2",
          command=lambda: do_something("Button 1")).pack()

# Is a button but does not change visuals when clicked due to state='disabled' and bind combination.
# Downside the text is greyed out.
button_2 = tk.Button(root, text="Button 2", relief='flat', bg="ghost white",
                     activebackground="LightSteelBlue2", state='disabled')
button_2.pack()
button_2.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: do_something("Button 2"))

# Is a label but works like a button due to bind.
# This method should fit your needs.
label_1 = tk.Label(root, text="Label 1", bg="ghost white", activebackground="LightSteelBlue2")
label_1.pack()
label_1.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: do_something("Label 1"))

root.mainloop()
```

Update:

Based on your comments below *"I want the button to change its color when is pressed and when is unpressed it returns to its normal state."* this is how I would get the functionality you are looking for.

```
import tkinter as tk


def change_color(event):
    event.widget.config(bg='green')
    entry.insert('end', event.widget['text'])


def change_back(event):
    event.widget.config(bg='ghost white')


root = tk.Tk()
num_pad = [[1, 2, 3],
           [4, 5, 6],
           [7, 8, 9]]

entry = tk.Entry(root, width=50)
entry.grid(row=0, column=0)

pad_frame = tk.Frame(root)
pad_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)
# Is a label but works like a button due to bind.
# This method should fit your needs.
for ndex, sub_list in enumerate(num_pad):
    for sub_ndex, sub_value in enumerate(sub_list):
        lbl = tk.Label(pad_frame, text=sub_value, bg="ghost white", activebackground="LightSteelBlue2",
                       height=2, width=3)
        lbl.grid(row=ndex, column=sub_ndex, padx=2, pady=2)
        lbl.bind("<Button-1>", change_color)
        lbl.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", change_back)
        lbl.bind("<Leave>", change_back)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment man. But I think I explainned wrong jajaja. I want the button to change its color when is pressed and when is unpressed it returns to its normal state. Look the edit of the post

Comment: You can still do this with a label. Let me see what works best.

Comment: Oh thank you! I didn't know I could do this with a label jajaja